# How do I upgrade OpenSSH Server on Ubuntu Hardy (8.04) from v4.7 to CURRENT?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, apt, ubuntu-8.04

I tried to add backports to my apt sources but that does not make any newer version of OpenSSH show up as being available to upgrade to. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want a newer version of openssh-server?  What feature do you require?  Why not do a full upgrade to 10.04?

Comment: Oh, and you might want to read that doc, they link to pages that describe the tools and method, that you could use to manually backport the packages yourself.